# Let Xcode Project build static library

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, build, static-libraries

I have a Core Library for my ios projects. I use this library in several projects.

When building the library, I copied the .a -file and the header-files into several xcode projects. Everything worked fine.

Now I would like that each project, which uses the library, build the library on their own.
I tried to use this runscript:

```
 # Build Core library first
CORE="${PWD}/../Core"
IDENT="PROJECTIDENT"


 PROJ=$CORE/Core.xcodeproj

CORE_LIB="${PWD}/Classes/Core"
mkdir -p "${CORE_LIB}"
#rm -rf "${CORE_LIB}/"*
mkdir -p "/tmp/${IDENT}"




 IS_EMPTY=`ls "${CORE_LIB}" | wc -l`


 if [ "true" == ${ALREADYINVOKED:-false} ]; then
       echo "ALREADY INVOKED"

 else

 # CRITICAL:
 # Prevent infinite recursion (Xcode sucks)
 export ALREADYINVOKED="true"


  SDK_VERSION=$(echo ${SDK_NAME} | grep -o '.\{3\}$')
  OUT_DIR="/tmp/${IDENT}"
  EXEC_NAME="libCore.a"
  UNIVERSAL_DIR="${OUT_DIR}/Universal"

  rm -rf "${UNIVERSAL_DIR}"
  mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_DIR}"

 CONFIG="Debug"
 if [ ${CONFIGURATION} != "Debug" ]; then
 CONFIG="Release"
fi

echo "${CONFIG}"

# Create build
 DID_COMPILE=`xcodebuild -project $PROJ -target Core -configuration "${CONFIG}" -sdk "${PLATFORM_NAME}${SDK_VERSION}" build RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER=NO BUILD_DIR="${OUT_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${OUT_DIR}" EXECUTABLE_NAME="${EXEC_NAME}" | grep "CompileC"`



 if [ ! -z "${DID_COMPILE}" ] || [ ${IS_EMPTY} -eq 0 ]; then

     # Copy Headers
     cp "${OUT_DIR}/${CONFIG}-${PLATFORM_NAME}/usr/local/include/"* "${UNIVERSAL_DIR}"
     cp "${OUT_DIR}/${CONFIG}-${PLATFORM_NAME}/${EXEC_NAME}"* "${UNIVERSAL_DIR}"

     # Finally we have a fat static library with .a and .h files
     # now we copy them to the Project
     rm -rf "${CORE_LIB}"
     cp -Rf "${UNIVERSAL_DIR}" "${CORE_LIB}"

fi

fi
```

This script works but only every second time.

E.g. I make a change in a Library Class, and built, the main project is not compiled while the Library dependency get refreshed.

Then I make another change to the Library, build again, and all changes are usable in the main probject.

But always only each second build....

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why you wont add your library xcodeproject file into each your project? When u compile your project library will be check and compiled if needed before your project compiled. thanks